# Spring custom scope with multiple prototypes

Tags: java, spring

I have this bean hierarchy in Spring: [image]

**Bean1**, **Bean2**, **Bean3** are all of scope prototype and of the same type (**Bean**) and must share the same instance of **AnotherBean**. Another bean must not be singleton, in order to manage the same situation:

```
public Test {

    @Autowired
    private Provider<Bean> beanProvider;

    public void testCustomScope() {

        Bean rootBean1 = beanProvider.get();
        Bean rootBean2 = beanProvider.get();

        // After that the following should be true
        // rootBean1.getAnotherBean() == rootBean1.getBean().getAnotherBean() == rootBean1.getBean().getBean().getAnotherBean()
        // rootBean2.getAnotherBean() == rootBean2.getBean().getAnotherBean() == rootBean2.getBean().getBean().getAnotherBean()
        // rootBean1.getAnotherBean() != rootBean2.getAnotherBean() and so on
    }
}
```

It seems to me that AnotherBean should be defined as a custom scope in Spring but I can't find a way to relate AnotherBean instances to the Bean instances.

What is the easiest way to manage this kind of scopes in Spring?

Thanks